# Extracting values with SpatialPointsDataFrame from Raster returns only NAs

Tags: r

I am a beginner in using R for spatial data analysis and want to simply extract some values for certain locations (with lon/lat positions) from a raster stack. However, when using extract(), it returns only NAs, so I guess I made a mistake with the projection.

I loaded the lon/lat-locations into a SpatialPointsDataFrame, changed the lon/lat into numeric and set the crs to EPSG:4326. 
The raster stack comes with the crs EPSG:3035, so I used "sftransform()" to project the lon/lat-locations accordingly. "compareCRS" for the two datasets gave the output "TRUE", so the projection supposedly worked. 
When I try to use extract(), however, it returns only NA's.

When I put the coordinates into Google Maps, they are mapped correctly, with mapview() in R, however, they seem to be completely off grid, so I supposed something about the projection went wrong, but I have no idea what. 
I hope that somebody here can help me out!

#### Loading in the raster stack named "texture"

```
> print(texture)
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 8073, 7781, 62816013, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 500, 500  (x, y)
extent     : 2635700, 6526200, 1385700, 5422200  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : Clay_eu23, Sand_eu23, Silt_eu23 
min values :         0,         0,         0 
max values :  76.47613, 100.00000,  91.61756
```

#### Loading in the DF with Lon/Lat Locations

```
  Datalogger        Lat       Lon
1        DL3 48.5932246 9.5576115
2        DL4 49.0160648 9.1887693
3        DL2 48.7100801 9.2141318
4       DL10 49.0038758 8.4934965
5        DL5 49.0034701 8.4954198
6        DL6 48.4183515 8.8958118
```

#### Changing the Lon/Lat columns to numeric

```
locations$Lon <- as.numeric(locations$Lon)
locations$Lat <- as.numeric(locations$Lat)
```

#### Setting the crs for the coordinates and creating SpatialPointsDF

```
coordinates(locations) <- ~Lon+Lat
proj4string(locations) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

> print(locations)
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 10 
extent      : 1, 10, 1, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 1
names       : Datalogger 
min values  :        DL1 
max values  :        DL9
```

#### Reprojecting the locations to the raster stack's (texture's) crs

```
loc_proj <- spTransform(locations, proj4string(texture))
```

#### Checking if crs is correct

```
compareCRS(texture, loc_proj)
```

#### Trying to extract values from rasterstack

```
values <- raster::extract(texture, loc_proj)
```

For values I only get NAs for each of the three rasters in the stack, even though when I call summary(texture) it returns valid data, and also the locations as such are valid. What did I do wrong with the projections?
Thank you very much already!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
locations$Lon <- as.numeric(locations$Lon)
locations$Lat <- as.numeric(locations$Lat)
```

You got

```
print(locations)
#class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
#features    : 10 
#extent      : 1, 10, 1, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

That is, your longitude and latitude are between 1 and 10. This suggest that `lon` and `lat` were factor variables (for whatever reason); and that you made a mistake in changing them to numeric.

Consider this

```
x <- as.factor(c(9.5576115, 9.1887693, 9.2141318, 8.4934965, 8.4954198, 8.8958118))
as.numeric(x)
#[1] 6 4 5 1 2 3
```

`as.numeric` does not use the factor labels in the conversion. It cannot do that because these labels may contain letters. Instead, it gives you the indices

So, instead, you should do

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
#[1] 9.557612 9.188769 9.214132 8.493496 8.495420 8.895812
```

In your code:

```
locations$Lon <- as.numeric(as.character(locations$Lon))
locations$Lat <- as.numeric(as.character(locations$Lat))
```